# How can I test "super" in a Chef resource?

Tags: super, chefspec

Is there an approach similar to `step_into` to encourage Chefspec to follow a resource's `super` call into its parent class? Or can you suggest an approach to test that the `super` call is followed (or not followed) as expected, to perform the appropriate action in the parent class?

e.g.,

```
class Child < Chef::Provider::Parent
  provides :child_resource
  def action_create
    # do childlike things
    super
  end
end

class Parent < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
  provides :parent_resource
  def action_create
    # do parental things
    file "/home/mine/#{new_resource.name}.json" do
      action :create
      content 'I am malformed json content'
    end
  end
end
```

with recipe

```
child_resource 'ima_potato' do
  property 'vegechair'
end
```

and tested with

```
require 'chefspec'

describe('procreate-concreate') do

  let(:child_runner) do
    memoized_runner('procreate-concreate', {step_into: ['child_resource', 'parent_resource']}, 'child_runner') do |node|
      # node things
    end
  end
    
  it 'creates the parent resource' do
    expect(child_runner).to create_parent_resource('ima_potato')
  end
    
  it 'creates the parent file' do
    expect(child_runner).to create_file('/home/mine/ima_potato.json')
  end
end
```

The above pattern works. My testing overlooked a missing boolean for a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The above pattern works. My testing overlooked a missing boolean for a conditional.